# VBA - Unable to set cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below in a master workbook to open workbooks listed in the range `E12:E24`.

- Once I have opened these workbooks, I need to count the number of open workbooks (in addition to the master workbook) and assign the number to cell E2 in the Portfolio Results sheet.
- The code below works just as I would like except I get an error message on the line    `Worksheets("Portfolio Results").Range("E2") = nFields`

It's unclear  to me why this is the case. Thanks for any help.

```
Sub SkipBlankCells2()

    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range, FName As String, nFields As Integer
    Set rng = Range("E12:E24")

    Application.DefaultFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    nFields = 0
    For Each cel In rng
        If Len(cel) >= 1 Then
                FName = cel.Value
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=FName
            nFields = nFields + 1
        End If
    Next cel
    Debug.Print nFields
    Worksheets("Portfolio Results").Range("E2") = nFields

End Sub
```

Comment: add wirkbbok name before     Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Portfolio Results").Range("E2") = nFields

Comment: That did it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *(almost always)* have `Option Explicit` as your first line of the code.

- Your current code contains an error, where you declared the variable

  ```
  Dim cell as Range
  ```
- but then in your `For` loop you're using an undeclared variable `cel` which defaults to a `Variant` data-type.
- with `Option Explicit` enabled, the compiler will warn you about these kind of errors.

---

As to the actual answer, when switching between objects (be it `Worksheet` or `Workbook`) it's always a good programming practice to explicitly declare them.

Easiest way to access them is to store them inside a variable:

```
Dim wb as Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("Static name")
Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Your sheet name")

'later in the code
    If wb.ws.Cells(1, 9) = "banana" Then '...
```

Not only this makes for a more read-able code for somebody else (because if somebody inherits your project, they can't know which `workbook` or `worksheet` intended the author to work with), but it also prevents these unnecessary kind of errors where a different `Workbook` or `Worksheet` is selected.

As a final note, if you don't know which `Workbook` might be open at the moment, but want to reference "this" specific one, then use `ThisWorkbook` instead

Comment: Thanks for the good advice Rawrplus. I will modify my code accordingly.

Comment: @reidarbb yeah no problem, would be nicei f you accepted the answer then please though, if all the problems have been solved. So the question can be 'closed'